# How to search through data using Laravel and Vue js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'd like to create a Search bar where Users can search and find matching results by 3 columns, job_title, company_name and country.

I was able to create a Search Filter through one of the columns using a computed property.

The problem is its returning matching records from the job_title column only, instead of all 3 columns. Is there a way to add multiple columns to this?
I tried `return jobPost.match(this.search);` instead of `return jobPost.job_title.match(this.search);` to maybe get the whole table but that just returned an error.

```
data() {
            return {
                jobPosts: [],
                search: ''

            };
        },
```

```
computed: {
            filteredJobs: function() {
                return this.jobPosts.filter((jobPost) => {
                    return jobPost.job_title.match(this.search);
                })
            }
        }
```

CandidateSearchController.php file:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->get('q');
        $jobPosts = JobPost::with('employerprofile')
            ->where('job_title', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->get();

        return Response::json(array(
            'jobPosts' => $jobPosts,
        ), 200);
    }
```

Search input and Button:

```
<input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search job titles.."/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 7px 10px; margin-top: -1px;">
   <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since  you have a single input you can use **OR in sql query** itself to match a given string to job title, company and country

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('q');
    $jobPosts = JobPost::with('employerprofile')
    ->where('job_title', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('job_title', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
           ->orWhere('company_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
           ->orWhere('country', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
    })
    ->get();

    return Response::json(array(
        'jobPosts' => $jobPosts,
    ), 200);
}
```